# How to get all feed history from feed burner chanel?

Tags: java, rss, feed, feedburner

I want to read all feeds from feedburner channel like [THIS](http://feeds.feedburner.com/HaveIBeenPwnedLatestPastes) using **java**, now trying with [ROME](http://rometools.github.io/rome/index.html) library but I'm only getting 50 entries. How to get all entries? I'm using the rome example code to read a syndication feed.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - Feedburner only has whatever entries the Original Feed provides to it 
at any given time.